# gitlab runner shell executor docker cache seems to be cleared after restarting systemd gitlab-runner unit

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using docker with the `shell` executor (https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html) in order to more effectively cache docker images being built.

I ran into an issue where after cancelling a job, pending jobs were not being started (seems to be an issue mentioned here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1662)

So I restarted gitlab-runner with `sudo systemctl restart gitlab-runner`, however now it seems the pipelines are running however it's building the docker images from scratch! As if the docker cache is completely gone...

**Why is it building the docker images from scratch again?**

Debugging:

Running `sudo -u gitlab-runner docker images` returns the list of images it has previously built, so I don't understand why it's not using this for the docker cache.